# How to move conditional error checks from NgIf to typescript file?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ng-if

In my Angular app, I need to add/remove CSS classes based on whether or not a FormControl has been touched, is dirty, is invalid, etc.

I'm using the ngClass directive to do this:

```
<div class="form-group has-required"
    [ngClass]="{'has-error':
        (conditionsForm.get('acceptTerms').touched || conditionsForm.get('acceptTerms').dirty)
         && conditionsForm.get('acceptTerms').errors}">
</div
```

Here is what I have in my Typescript currently:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.conditionsForm = this.fb.group({
        acceptTerms: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        insuredType: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        reportInjury: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    });
}
```

As the above conditional is quite long, I would like to move it into my Typescript file.

Is there a particular method to doing this? I'm not sure how I can do it. Can someone please tell me what my approach should be?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with this which will work for all formControls:

```
public hasError(formControlName: string): boolean {
 if (this.user.get(formControlName).errors) {
  return true;
 }
 else {
  return false;
 }
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'has-error': hasError('acceptTerms')}">
// Other HTML
</div>
```

So in case of other form controls you can easily use it as:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'has-error': hasError('another_formcontrol')}">
 //
</div>
```

[`Working_Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tesj8a-iy3akt)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this solution is what I'm looking for as it's reusable. But when I merge your code with mine, I'm getting the following console error in `hasError()`: _Type 'ValidationErrors' is not assignable to type 'boolean'_

Comment: Thanks for that, but now the error CSS class is appearing OnInit(), but I only want the error to display if the form control is invalid & has been touched. To solve this, I just added a `.touched` check inside your `if` condition

Answer (score 1):

You can just wrap it into a function in your component:

```
public _hasErrorClass(): boolean {
  return (this.conditionsForm.get('acceptTerms').touched || this.conditionsForm.get('acceptTerms').dirty)
         && this.conditionsForm.get('acceptTerms').errors;
}
```

And then use it in your template:

```
<div class="form-group has-required" [ngClass]="{'has-error': _hasErrorClass()}"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try another route: Angular OOTB assigns classes such as `ng-dirty`, `ng-touched`, `ng-invalid` to form controls, you can style those in the component's stylesheet.

```
input.ng-invalid.ng-dirty {
  // style definition here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you needs to check both dirty and touched. Checkout the reactive form documentation - https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

```
<div class="form-group has-required"
    [ngClass]="{'has-error':  conditionsForm.acceptTerms.touched && conditionsForm.acceptTerms.errors}">
</div>
```